# I am creating google polyline from an array and increment the array with a for loop, but the polyline is not drawn

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is an simple form of question for a bigger problem, I have narrowed down my problem to this piece of code I want some help.

I am trying to give the coordinate of the path i traveled to an array from a for loop, the array has the values but the polyline is not plotting.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

var flightPlanCoordinates =[];
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    flightPlanCoordinates[i] = [new google.maps.LatLng(i,i)];

    }


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = flightPlanCoordinates;  /*this is just to check if array has values*/
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 6.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript error in the posted code:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

on this line:

```
flightPlanCoordinates[i] = [new google.maps.LatLng(i,i)];
```

That should be:

```
flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(i,i);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(i, i);

  }


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = flightPlanCoordinates; /*this is just to check if array has values*/
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 6.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a silly question indeed, i should have researched better.